# safe alternative to UNSAFE_componentWillMount?

Tags: react-native

I have an app that uses class based components. In the process of converting it from flow to typescript in line with current trends I realised that componentWillMount has ben deprecated and is no longer safe to use. I'm not sure what to do with it as this is in a class based component and converting it all into function components will take too long. I tried componentDidMount, but I got an error saying that setState should not be used in componentDidMount:

```
  UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
    this._setupPanResponder();
    this.setState({ date: this.props.date });
  }
```

Is there a safe alternative to this that doesn't involve changing the component to a function component?

Answer (score 1):

Can you move it to constructor?

Something like:

```
...
constructor(props: PropsType) {
  super(props);
  
  this._setupPanResponder();
  this.state = { date: props.date };
}
...
```